# how to put 3 different tikz pictures into a page width

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, resize

My page is arranged as a two column. I have 3 different tikzpicture in one figure. I want to put these 3 tikzpictures that fit in page width not column width. Can you please help me to do this?

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.40]
          \begin{axis}[
            title={rate},
            ymin=1, ymax=5,
            xmin=1, xmax=5,
            xtick = {1,2,3,4,5},
            xticklabels = {1,2,3,4,5},
        ]%original
        \addplot[black,line width=0.5mm]
            plot coordinates {
                (1, 3) 
                (2, 5) 
                (3, 4) 
                (4, 2) 
                (5, 1)
            };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \caption{caption1} \label{fig:M1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.40]
        \begin{axis}[
            title={rate2},
            ymin=1, ymax=5,
            xmin=1, xmax=5,
            xtick = {1,2,3,4,5},
            xticklabels = {1,2,3,4,5},
        ]%majority 
        \addplot[black, mark=diamond*]
            plot coordinates {
                (1, 3) 
                (2, 1) 
                (3, 4) 
                (4, 2) 
                (5, 5)
            };
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}}
      \caption{caption2} \label{fig:M2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.40]
      \begin{axis}[
    title={rate},
    ymin=1, ymax=5,
    xmin=1, xmax=5,
    xtick = {1,2,3,4,5},
    xticklabels = {1,2,3,4,5},
    ]%original
    \addplot[black,line width=0.5mm]
    plot coordinates {
        (1, 1) 
        (2, 5) 
        (3, 3) 
        (4, 2) 
        (5, 4)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \caption{caption3} \label{fig:M3}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Accuracy}
\end{figure}[![accuracy][1]][1]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use `figure*` instead of `figure`.

Comment: If you need further help, please make your code compilable.